# How to make this HTML template work with PHP?

Tags: php, html, templates

First of all, I'm a noob and probably I'm asking something easy to do.
I have this small template saved in template2.html :

```
<table border=”0″> <tr>
                     <td align=”center”><!-- IDCAT --></td>
                     <td><!-- CATEGORIA --></td>
                   </tr>

</table>
```

This db connection file in php mysql3.php :

```
    <?php
          $connessione = @mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","tecwebdb") or die("La connessione al Database è fallita !");
          $sql = "SELECT ID_Categoria,Nome FROM categoria";

          $query=@mysqli_query($connessione, $sql) or die("Esecuzione Query fallita !");
     ?>
```

And the php code for make it all works in this file test.php:

```
 <?php

include("mysql3.php"); 
$file_content = implode("",file("template2.html"));


while($ris=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $output = preg_replace("<!-– IDCAT -->", $ris["ID_Categoria"], $file_content);
    $output = preg_replace("<!–- CATEGORIA -->", $ris["Nome"], $output);

   echo $output;
}

@mysqli_close($connessione);

?>
```

The problem is that the query results are not showing probably I'm missing something on the while cicle, how to make it work?

Comment: you can also have HTML codes in your php file.

Comment: Start by removing all `@`-signs in front of your calls. `@` suppresses any errors thrown by those calls and you should read about how to handle the errors correctly instead. Any errors might give you information about why your code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Your regular expression is flawed, you are missing the beginning and ending `/`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because your Regx is flawed  ( as I said in the comments )

```
  $output = preg_replace("<!-– IDCAT -->", $ris["ID_Categoria"], $file_content);
```

Try:

```
  $output = preg_replace("/<!-– IDCAT -->/", $ris["ID_Categoria"], $file_content);
```

Your basically missing the delimiters `/` at the start and end of the Regx, I imagine PHP is issuing a warning for this, too.  Which if you had display errors on `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` you would see.

Or just use `str_replace()`  which is more the appropriate function to use in this case, IMO.

```
  $output = str_replace("<!-– IDCAT -->", $ris["ID_Categoria"], $file_content);
```

You can try it here

https://regex101.com/r/ObyMbZ/1

But note they put the delimiters in for you automatically, which is what you are missing.

Update: change this

```
   while($ris=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
```

to

```
    while($ris=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
```

So your array will have keys, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Thank you, I've added the / but still nothing is showing.

Comment: Pratically I have 2 rows, who are the 2 results that the query should give me back, but nothing printed inside the cells

Comment: do `print_r($ris)` just inside the loop to see what the contents of the data are...

Comment: you also are not using the correct mysqli function `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()`  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php  because you want an associative array and not a numerically indexed array.

Comment: ok, added mysqli_fetch_assoc() and tried to print, and the results are ok there, but they still doesn't appear in the table

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating it a bit too much.

You can do it all in 1 file (e.g. `test.php`) as below:

```
<?php

//connect to DB
$connessione = @mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","tecwebdb") or die("La connessione al Database è fallita !");
$sql = "SELECT ID_Categoria,Nome FROM categoria";
$query=@mysqli_query($connessione, $sql) or die("Esecuzione Query fallita !");

//render the table
?>
    <table border=”0″>
    <?php
        while($ris=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
        {

            echo "<tr>";//row start
            echo "<td align='center'>".$ris["ID_Categoria"]."</td>"; //col
            echo "<td>".$ris["Nome"]."</td>";//col
            echo "</tr>"; //row end
        }
    ?>
    </table>
<?php
//close the connection
@mysqli_close($connessione);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I know that I can do it all in 1 file, but this is an exercise I'm doing for school, so I have to make it work with those 3 files, expecially with the template replace for showing the query results

Comment: @LucaPearl, ah ok. Please explain this in your question next time :) No worries!

Answer (score 0):

replace this :

```
 $output = preg_replace("<!-– IDCAT -->", $ris["ID_Categoria"], $file_content);
$output = preg_replace("<!–- CATEGORIA -->", $ris["Nome"], $output);
```

With this :

```
     $output = preg_replace("<!-- IDCAT -->", $ris["payer_id"], $file_content);
   $output = preg_replace("<!-- CATEGORIA -->", $ris["description"], $output);
```

Comment: I have no Idea where you got this from, but the regx is still incorrect as I mentioned in both the comments and my answer.  Missing the delimiters `/`